# How do I prevent multiple paypal payments in nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, paypal, payment-gateway

I am really new to node js and trying to integrate Paypal's Payment Gateway into my application.

Upon the success of the payment, the user is redirected to `http://localhost:3000/success?paymentId=PAYID-M8MU148234F&token=EC-2111Y&PayerID=YX82JX6Q` where our code executes the order and return a payment object (contains order details).

On this page, I want to display the order details to the user.

1. I want to store the payment object as a JSON.stringify into my Mongoose database for future reference. The issue is that if the user keeps on reloading this page, the code inside app.get('/success'..) will keep on adding the same columns to the mongoose database repeatedly. I am not sure how to prevent that.
2. Since the payment is **actually executed** only when this URL is visited by the user, multiple reloads by the user blocks me from Paypal API and gives me the following error:

```
response: {
    name: 'MAX_NUMBER_OF_PAYMENT_ATTEMPTS_EXCEEDED',
    message: 'You have exceeded the maximum number of 20 payment attempts.',
    information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors',..........
```

The only solution I can think of right now is that somehow my `/success` route executes the payment and stores the data onto the database and then redirects the user to maybe `/someOtherPage/` page with the order details as headers. I am not sure how to make this redirect happen and also pass some context (the payment object) at the same time.

Comment: Also, I want the user to see the order details just once (since it is a guest checkout). So, I don't want to store the payment object onto my database and load a dynamic page like **/someOtherPage/:id** which loads info from the JSON string I saved into my database earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a deprecated v1/payments API and/or PayPal-Node-SDK.  You should change your integration to the current v2/checkout/orders and Checkout-NodeJS-SDK.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

The above mostly takes care of this issue and is the recommended solution, as it does not rely on redirects and gives an improved user experience that increases buyer confidence by keeping your site loaded in the background. But to more directly address the issue posed here: when doing an execute or capture API call, set the `PayPal-Request-Id` HTTP header to something that will persist across retries that are not expected to result in new actions/transactions -- for example simply set this header to the PAYID or OrderId being acted on. This will give idempotent behavior (see [API idempotency](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/develop/idempotency/))

Comment: I went through the documentation and it feels a little overwhelming. What does it exactly mean by creating and capturing an order? I also see there is something called "Authorize the order" and "Get order details"

Comment: ```<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>```
Hello. What are we supposed to replace those script tag on the client side?

Comment: I seemed to have included a pretty decent system in now. I am getting the following error now -```Error: Identitysecuretokenserv responded with status 401 for securityContext``` on the Console.

Comment: Update: It's working now. Refreshed the server and browser and it worked. 1. Where does the user see 'the merchant's information' while making the payment? 2. How to change the store name? The dialogue box currently says 'Cancel and return to the TEST store' 3. Does the return JSON string specify the name of the product only if we have specified it in the full-parameter list?

Comment: I was getting some promise errors when I was assigning the return value of execute() to a const in the try{} block. The moment I declared it using **let** outside and then executed, it worked fine. I was wondering why? Also, is it fine to display the CLIENT_ID on the frontend as part of the script tag?

Comment: Store name comes from the receiving account's business name, although it can be overridden in the v2 orders create object. Client IDs are public. You'll have to test the description or items list as far as what is returned at capture time or with a get call, but you can keep track of that yourself. You should verify the total when capturing.